# How to find whether value is integer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to perform some task based on some ifs

my (uncomplete) code is

```
Sub checkif()
    Dim s
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        s = Val(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count)
        s = s / 5
            If s = Integer then
                perform some task
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
     End With
End Sub
```

I am completely new to VBA and there are so many answers. I have tried several.
one is

```
Sub checkif2()
    Dim s
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        s = Val(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count)
        s = s / 5
            If IsNumeric(s) Then
            MsgBox "is integer"
            Else
            MsgBox "not integer"
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This always give integer.

checked another one

```
Sub checkif2()
    Dim s
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        s = Val(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count)
        s = s / 5
            If TypeName(s) = "Integer" Then
            MsgBox "is integer"
            Else
            MsgBox "not integer"
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Always give not integer.
Is there any method for Word VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If s = Fix(s)` is one way.

`Fix` strips off the fractional part.

Another approach in your case would be to check if the base 5 modulus is zero prior to taking the division. Use `Mod` for that: `If s Mod 5 = 0`.

Comment: For me, I want to check weather my file contains paragraphs count in multiple of five. Will this give correct answers in every case? I mean can I use If s = Fix(s) then Will work for this? I think It should from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

While trying Rahul's answer, Found that This is simplest way.

```
If s = Int(s) Then
```

Tried for smaller file.
I will check with larger files and tell.

Comment: Be careful: I think that `Int(s)` will round any fractional part. That's why I use `Fix(s)`.

Comment: Oh!!!. I will fix with Fix(s) then. I am completely novice. Will keep this in mind.